# How can I replace particular values in my data.frame depending on their value?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (concerning prostate cancer survival) and one of the factor variables "stage" only has 4 observations for stage 3. I want to combine stage 3 with stage 2 before doing regression. Is there a function that will search through the stage data and if stage = 3, change this value to 2?

Many thanks!

I have tried:

```
pro$stage[pro$stage==3] <- 2
```

but this doesnt seem to do the trick

Comment: I don't see a reason why your code shouldn't work. Try closing and restarting R.

Comment: Agree with @RuiBarradas. If this is not working, will you be able to show your code segment?

Comment: This is the error message I get: > pro$stage[pro$stage==3]<-2
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, pro$stage == 3, value = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Answer (score 0):

With a dataframe this should work.

```
pro <- data.frame(name=seq(1:10),disease=rep("Cancer"),stage=round(runif(n=10,min = 1,max = 3)),survival=round(runif(n=10,min = 0,max = 1)))
pro
pro$stage[pro$stage==3]
pro$stage[pro$stage==3] <- 2
pro
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pro$stage <- ifelse(pro$stage==3,2,pro$stage)
```